# Practical use of State or Strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I have this in my code

```
switch (auctionType)
                {
                    case AuctionTypes.OpenBid:
                        destination = new EnglishAuction();
                        break;
                    case AuctionTypes.FixedPrice:
                        destination = new BuyoutAuction();
                        break;
                    case AuctionTypes.ClosedBid:
                        destination = new SealedFirstPriceAuction();
                        break;
                    default:
                        destination = new Auction();
                        break;
                }
```

What I am wondering is how do I eliminate the switch statement by using the Strategy or State pattern?

Comment: Not what you are looking for but in Java you could add a method createAuction() to each value of your enum and do destination = auctionType.createAuction().

Comment: That code looks like part of an `AuctionFactory` which produces `Auction` objects to be used as an Auction Strategy by something else.

Comment: This looks like a usecase of factory rather than strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, and with reference to @Raphaël's comment about a way of eliminating the switch statement in Java, you could get a similar result (albeit with more work) in C# like this:

Create an attribute which holds a `Type` and creates an instance of it using its parameterless constructor:

```
public class TypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public TypeAttribute(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public T CreateInstance()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
    }
}
```

...decorate your `enum` with the attribute:

```
public enum AuctionTypes
{
    [Type(typeof(EnglishAuction))]
    OpenBid,

    [Type(typeof(BuyoutAuction))]
    FixedPrice,

    [Type(typeof(SealedFirstPriceAuction))]
    ClosedBid,

    [Type(typeof(Auction))]
    Default
}
```

...add an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Auction CreateAuction(this AuctionTypes auctionType)
    {
        return typeof(AuctionTypes)
            .GetMember(auctionType.ToString())
            .First()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TypeAttribute), inherit: false)
            .Cast<TypeAttribute>()
            .First()
            .CreateInstance<Auction>();
    }
}
```

...which you can call like this:

```
var auction = auctionType.CreateAuction();
```

That's from memory and would be better if we had generic attributes, but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is indeed a factory. In a factory, switches are OK.

The `Auction` objects you return probably belong to a strategy. The difference between strategy and state is subtle, but important:

- In a **strategy**, you're using different algorithms to accomplish *essentially* the same thing. The caller must not need to know this, it's an implementation detail. Some examples of strategies might be

  - In a computer game, you want your AI bad guys to attack the player. Different enemies might use different strategies because they might be able to fly over obstacles, teleport to the player or have different combat style.
  - In a `HybridDictionary`, operations might be implemented in a simple `ListDictionary` while the collection is small and use a `Hashtable` once the collection grows.
  - In a CAD application, you might have implemented different strategies to calculate the solution for a complex equation depending on a variety of factors to find the optimal level of speed vs. accuracy.

  This sometimes leads to confusion, because the different monster's behavior is 'obvious' or at least visible to the end-user, while the latter aren't. On the other hand, it *is* visible because it's hopefully faster / more precise. It's just not that obvious, usually.
- in a **State** pattern, on the other hand, the class will behave differently. The classical state pattern example is a `TcpSocket` class: The socket could be, among others, in connected or disconnected state. This is visible to the client, and calling `Disconnect()` on a disconnected socket is an error, as is calling `Connect()` on a socket that is already connected. The object itself can change its state, and it's visible and known to the outside.

Since you are using a factory, the `Auction` object returned will probably not change type during its lifetime as part of the normal operation. Implementations of state typically don't go through a factory because they are not interchangeable. Instead, you would create a `TcpSocket` which uses `TcpSocketClosed` internally and changes to `TcpSocketConnected` after you successfully called `Connect()`.